# Python beginner's prob

Tags: python

so i made 3 games and tried to merge them together but had a problem with the first one.

this is the game before merging

```py
def Average_Game(arg , *list):

    result = arg

    for var in list:
        result = result + var

    print(result)

    print(result/len(list))
```

then I tried it here but it keeps giving me errors

```py
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        print('Welcome to the Full Game')
        print('Please choose the Game you want to play')
        print('Press[1] for Average Game')
        print('Press[2] for MultiblicationTable Game')
        print('Press[3] for Even-Odd Game')

        self.choices()


    def choices(self):
        while True:
            your_choice = input('Please Enter your Choice : ')

            try:
                your_choice = int(your_choice)

                if your_choice == 1:
                    self.Average_Game()

            except ValueError:
                Print('Please enter a valid number')    

    #############################################################################

    def Average_Game(self , *list):

        result = self

        for var in list:
            result = result + var

        print(result)

        print(result/len(list))

        game1 = Game()
```

it gives me this error and I can't understand it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:/Python34/Full Game 2.py", line 43, in <module>
    game1 = Game()

 File "C:/Python34/Full Game 2.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.choices()

  File "C:/Python34/Full Game 2.py", line 21, in choices
    self.Average_Game()

  File "C:/Python34/Full Game 2.py", line 37, in Average_Game
    print(result/len(list))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Game' and 'int'
```

Comment: You might want to not use list...its a protected keyword.

Comment: If you replace `result = self` with `result = 0` it should work. But it begs the question, why are you doing that?

Comment: As a beginner it can be useful to learn about how to create a [mcve]. There is a lot of code (and back story) in this question which is irrelevant. If you try to recreate the error with as little code as possible, you can often realise your problem, or at least have a better question to search for an existing answer. And if all that fails, you'll have a concise formulation of your problem: *"why does dividing `self` by an integer fail?"*

Comment: @PeterWood wow! That's a very good explanation for a problem I see alot here on Stack. Don't mind if I save it for later use?

Comment: @JasonChia list is not a keyword (it couldn't be shadowed then e.g. you can't create a local variable called `def` or `async`), it's a builtin.

Comment: @Masklinn well im not quite sure what the exact term is but using list as a variable name is a no-no... just pointing that out.

Comment: `Multiblication` [That's the Name of the Game](https://www.lyricsfreak.com/b/bobby+darin/multiplication_20525388.html)?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Go ahead. I often type out similar things. I should probably save my blurbs somewhere. Just to note, if you put `[mcve]` it automatically expands to [mcve]. Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: @PeterWood yeah I am familiar with the mcve shortcut, thanks! And no problem, it's just that I get to see around here a lot of questions telling a whole story with why they are doing this code, and just throwing all of it inside, instead of focusing the question on the specific issue. You just worded it very nicely and informatively, well done!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you can't understand. The message tells you you're trying to divide a game by an integer in Average_Game, and where, removing the irrelevant bits:

```py
    def Average_Game(self , *list):
        result = self
        print(result/len(list))
```

meaning you're trying to divide `self` by `len(list)`, and since `Average_Game` is a method of the `Game` class, `self` is an instance of the `Game` class.

I've no idea what this is supposed to be, but I assume `result` should be the sum of all ??? in `list`, therefore you should have

```py
        result = 0

        for var in list:
            result = result + var
```

or just

```py
        result = sum(list)
```

Furthermore, you're not handling the situation where `list` is empty, in which case you're going to execute `0/0` which... isn't going to work.

Incidentally, your `list` parameter:

- really should not be called list: aside from that name explaining nothing about the purpose or semantics of it, `list`  is [a builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) and it's bad style (and risky) to shadow these
- is not even a list, star-args are collected as a tuple
- has no reason to be a star-arg, it should just be a regular parameter

Comment: `*list` in a method/function definition is the same as `*args` that is ordinarily used, which means that it accepts any number of positional arguments, including 0. He's also overwriting the keyword `list` inside of that method.

Comment: @HampusLarsson yes? I never said it was anything else, I only noted in passing that it shadows a builtin (not a method), and that it's a tuple not a list (because star-args are collected as a tuple).